# I need to capture the warning message for input field but my logic is not able to create the scenario

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I need to capture the mandatory warning message for a input field and my scenario is

1. i have to click on input field
2. i need to enter the data
3. and i have to clear the enter data again

expected : It should show the mandatory warning message

actual : but it is not showing the warning message

but i observed is, in manual time, focus is not shifting while doing actions on input field.. but when i clear the text the focus is missing from the field..so is it impacting the scenario?

**code:**

```
   await po.name().click();
   await po.name().clear();
   browser.sleep(3000);
   await po.name().sendKeys("saas");
   await po.name().clear();
   browser.sleep(3000);
   expect(po.msg().isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
```

can some one help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

```
   await po.name().click();
   await po.name().clear();
   browser.sleep(3000);
   await po.name().sendKeys("saas");
   await browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.BACKSPACE).perform();
   browser.sleep(3000);
   expect(po.msg().isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
po.name().sendKeys("s");
po.name().sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
```